# Estimating complicated conditional probabilities with less calculation/computation

Tags: conditional-probability, importance-sampling, data-generating-process

How can we estimate P(A | B & C & D & E) with reasonable accuracy by only calculating something like P(A | B), P(A | C), P(A | D), P(A | E), P(A | B & C), P(A | B & E), P(A | C & D), and P(A | D & E)? Also, what is the best way to go about choosing the probabilities that we calculate?

**Context:**

If I have a dataset with categorical columns whose values have an arbitrary combination of dependency with each other; what is an efficient way to generate new data that looks like it, respecting as many conditional probabilities as possible?

Case 1:
There are 1000 rows and 4 columns. The unique values of the columns are {0,1}, {0,1,2,3,4}, {0,1,2,3}, and {0,1}. Here, it is easy enough to calculate any conditional probability I like. A potential procedure is as follows:

1. Pick 0 or 1 for the first column, according to the frequency of the
   data. (e.g., if 60% are 0s, and 40% are 1s, then 60% of the time, I
   will pick 0.)
2. Pick among 0-4 for column two, weighting according to P(column 2 | column 1) as seen in the original data.
3. Proceed for other columns this way, for example, P(column 4 | column 1 & column 2 & column 3). The order you choose to pick the values (columns) could be changed.

Case 2:
There are 10^5 rows and 69 columns. The columns may be something like in the first case, each with various size of possible values. It is impractical to build a database of every conditional probability, as the combination of all possible values, N, is 2^N - 1. However, if the original data is accessible, then it is not too difficult to calculate the probabilities as needed and performs the same process as described in Case 1.

The challenge is now is how to improve performance further without damaging the accuracy of the result too much. We may choose only to sample the data when making calculations to the degree that the representation will not greatly suffer.

In practice, there may also be many attributes missing not at random.

**Toy Data:**
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CUBICinfinity/Unproject/main/conditional_values.csv

Comment: Your key requirement, "respecting as many conditional probabilities as possible," is so vague and general that the question becomes difficult to pin down or answer.  Could you be more specific about what this phrase means?

Comment: @whuber I can attempt. I don't think the target is a fixed value of accuracy. Instead, I think that I'm interested in knowing how to choose features to quickly get to a good answer and how what I choose will affect the accuracy of the answer. Probably, a good start would be to target the point at which there is some kind of inflection (higher jerk or deceleration), if such a point exists, where adding more information does not significantly improve the accuracy. If no clear inflection point exists, then let's say I want a 95% "confidence" interval of +/- 3%.

Comment: By respecting conditional probabilities, I mean that any dependency that exists in the dataset which is relevant to predicting the likelihood of a feature is taken into consideration, so long as there is sufficient data to support the relationship. That's still probably too vague, but see the last comment. The main objective is to faithfully generate new data such that a person who sees the new data would have a pretty good understanding of the world that the original data came from.

Comment: Key concepts like "choose features quickly" remain vague.  If you are trying to *estimate* (not "calculate") a conditional probability from the data, then why not do so directly rather than going through some kind of intermediate calculation based on "choosing features," whatever that might mean?  Ultimately, how you estimate probabilities depends on the assumptions you make about the joint distribution.  Furthermore, "Improve performance further" and "damaging the accuracy" both require you to specify *quantitative* metrics for both that objective and that constraint.